# how to add specific visualization to histogram

Tags: kibana-4

I use Kibana to create a date histogram of some web traffic, tagged by category. Using an algorithm running somewhere else, I know that a certain histogram value was an anomaly, and I can export that data into Elasticsearch. 
But I can't figure out how to make Kibana visualize the combination of the two in one graph, something like I sketched in the picture below, where the red outline indicates the anomaly.

[image: date histogram]

The anomaly data are just records with timestamp and count values. I can visualize those separate from the histogram easily:

[image: anomalies over time]

Any hints on how to combine these two series ?

Thanks

Bart

Comment: You should create a dashboard and add these 2 visualizations to it which will help you easily visualize both of the series together.

Comment: I'm doing that, but I don't find it visually appealing, and I'm also running out of screen real-estate, since I have quite a lot more to show.